# Write Queries on Excel sheet in c#

Tags: excel

I want to update specific row of excel sheet from my asp.net application. I m able to read excel, but how can i update the records.Can i write Update query . How . please send me code:

```
        string strQuery = "UPDATE [Sheet1$]  SET Child Name=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[0] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Pickup Point Name=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[1] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Pickup Bus No=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[2] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Pickup Bus Time=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[3] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Drop Down Point Name=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[4] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Drop Bus No=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[5] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Drop Down Bus Time=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[6] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Parent Name=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[7] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Mobile 1=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[8] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Mobile 2=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[9] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Email ID 1=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[10] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Email ID 2=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[11] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "Service Mode=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[12] + "\",";
        strQuery = strQuery + "WHERE Child Id=" + strDataToUpdate[13];
```

This Query i am using giving Syntax error.Please guide

Comment: what update? what record? what excel sheet?

Comment: r u from this planet ?? come on dude... Simply i want to update the Excel sheet (for ur information MS Excel Ok? :) by using the update query of ODBC connection. Well i think u r not from s/w background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can do it.

You can see live ASP.NET samples with C# and VB source code [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 2):

you can use it through **ADO.NET**. This is explained [here](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx)

Comment: Good link u had forwarded, I followed it  but Adeel I make the connection with ODBC . So can u send me regards of same.Actually I can't change my existing code, so hope u understatnd. Please it is too urgent. I need proper syntax for Update Query on excel sheet through c#.

Comment: Adeel I tried link , but getting error :
ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Answer (score 0):

when your field name consist space, you must put filed name in brakets for example:

```
string strQuery = "UPDATE [Sheet1$]  SET [Child Name]=" + "\"" + strDataToUpdate[0] + "\",";
```